# Workspaces-Action URL to Item Master Maint. Screen

Tags: navigator, exact-synergy-enterprise

I am trying to get a menu item in a workspaces report to bypass the item master search screen, and go straight to the item master maintenance screen by using the "|{1}" switch mentioned below here:

*Parameters for Exact Macola Launches*

*Some of the Exact Macola launches take a parameter that allows you to skip the search
screen and go directly to a specific entity; these are typically maintenance screens (for
example, Item Master Maintenance).
To pass the item number to this program, add the following to the Action URL “|{1}”. This
consists of a separator value “|” and then “{1}” to indicate passing the first parameter to
this menu item. That number would change depending on which parameter to pass. When
this is launched from the report it opens the Item Master Maintenance screen for the specific
item. To pass multiple parameters (up to 20), enter the information like this (use the
table “Parameters to Pass for Exact Macola Screens” on page 88 to determine how many
parameters can be passed for each launch): |{1}{2}{3}{4}*

When I add the switch, I get the following error:

**The ActionInfo.Action.Hyperlink expression for the text box ‘ITEM’ contains an error: [BC30455] Argument not specified for parameter 'Division' of 'Public Shared Function ContextualMenu(MenuID As String, ReportID As String, Division As String, FieldValue1 As String, FieldValue2 As String, FieldValue3 As String, FieldValue4 As String) As Object'**.

If anyone has an example of how this should be constructed I would appreciate the help. Here it is in it's current form that is creating the error.

=UFssrsCA.CAFunctions.ContextualMenu|{1}("Item_no",Variables!ReportID.Value,Parameters!ReportParameter1.Value,Fields!item_no.Value, "", "", "")

Thanks!

Scott Johnson